# Node id of home page

Tags: nodes, routes

If I choose a node to be the home page, how can I get its node id in the page template?

Can `menu_get_item()` be used for this?

Answer (score 4):

@Oswald: thanks for pointing in the right direction. This snippet does exactly what I need:

```
$front_url = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
$front_url = trim($front_url, '/');
$front = explode('/', $front_url);
if( $front[0]=='node' && ctype_digit($front[1]) ) {
  $front_nid = $front[1];
}
echo $front_nid;
```

Answer (score 3):

The drupal path of the home page is stored in the drupal variable `site_frontpage`. You can access it using

```
$site_frontpage = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
```

You can find out whether this is a node page using something like

```
list($first, $second) = explode('/', $site_frontpage, 2);
if ($first == 'node' && is_numeric($second)) {
  // It's a node page and the node id is stored in $second.
} else {
  // It's not a node page.
}
```